# Java Update Files

Tags: windows-7, java

Win7 64-bit

I've noticed in the control panel > Programs and features

i have 3 Java Update installations

namely...

- Java(TM) 6 update 30
- Java(TM) 6 update 30 (64-bit)
- Java(TM) 7 update 5

i usually install the latest one whenever it comes out so i assume they are there because of that and that the older versions are legacy files?

Can i happily uninstall the older version(6) files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by going through the programs that you have that need Java and check their system requirements to see if they need a specific version. If none seem to require Java 6, then you can uninstall those two versions. And even if it later turns out that something does need Java 6, then you can just reinstall it (previous versions of Java are available [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html)).